# Error: Could not determine active Firebase project directory in firebase while switching account with firebase login:use

Tags: bash, flutter, firebase, command-line-interface

I used Firebase CLI to create a new firebase project for my flutter app. now, my client wants to use another email with it's own firebase project. That project already has the datas (production data) that I need. However after doing firebase login:add  I have added both the emails, now when I do firebase login:use , I'm getting

`Error: Could not determine active Firebase project directory`

`Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help`

in my cli. I hope my question was clear. thank you for reading this far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this command: `firebase login --reauth`
It generates a link on the terminal which redirects you to Google Sign In on the web, where you can choose an new account to log in with.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I was not in the right directory. To use `firebase login:use` the command, you must be in a Firebase project directory (the project generated by the `firebase init` command).

It's strange that you must be in a Firebase project to change your account since other `firebase login` commands can be done outside a Firebase project.